# How do you get the properties, operators and values from an Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, expression-trees, func

Is there any way to pull out the properties, the operator and matching value from an `Expression<Func<T>,bool>`? Given the following example:

```
var customers = GetCustomers();
var customerQuery = customers.Where(x=> x.CustomerID == 1 
    && x.CustomerName == "Bob"); // The query is for illustration only
```

I need to be able to get out something like the following:

```
Property: CustomerID
Operator: Equals
Value:    1

Property: CustomerName
Operator: Equals
Value:    Bob
```

I've already written something that can pull out the property name of an Expression, but I cannot seem to find out where the value and operator are held, although it's quite clearly visible in the Expression's DebugView property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operator will be on the `BinaryExpression`'s `Method` that is the `Equals` node. You should also look at the expressions `.NodeType`, which reveals much (it should be `Equal`).

The *values* will typically be in a `ConstantExpression` in the `.Right` of that `BinaryExpression`, or in the case of a captured variable: the *capture-context* will be the `ConstantExpression`, so the *value* will be a `MemberExpression` over a `ConstantExpression` (you will need to investigate whether the member is a `FieldInfo` vs `PropertyInfo`, and fetch the value via `.GetValue(...)` on that).

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Just had to cast `predicate` using `(BinaryExpression)predicate.Body` and now everything's rather obvious. Cheers Marc.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Marc Gravells answer (+1 there) I'll just add that it's worth taking a look at the [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) class (out of the box in .Net 4; MSDN has an example that you can copy/paste for 3.5).  It makes writing code to extract certain types of expression very very easy.

In your case you would be looking to override it's [`VisitBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.visitbinary.aspx) method.

I typically use the class to push the expression(s) I'm interested in into a read-only list, for example, which I then make available publicly on my implementation of the class.  You're not using it to rewrite the expression.

Comment: +1, thanks. It certainly makes it easier to find the Binary Expressions, but I'll leave Marc's answer as accepted as it says how to pull out the information I require.

Comment: Yes I agree - Marc's answer gives you the nuts and bolts for this question and deserves the tick; mine is only offering a simple way to achieve what he's suggested :)